# Out of Scope Objects in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I am using an [audio-player package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/player) to play a sound locally when a node app triggers an event.  When the event is triggered, a function is called with the specific file that needs to be opened as such:

```
playSound(fileName);
```

The separate function looks like this:

```
player = new Player('someDirectory/' + fileName + '.mp3');
player.play();
```

This opens and begins playing the file perfectly well, however when events trigger in quick succession, both sounds will be simultaneously playing.  While I initially thought to simply add a:

```
player.stop();
```

before the 'new Player' definition, the previous instance is clearly out of scope, as the function has been called a second time.  How can I stop all other instances of Player before starting playback anew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the `player` variable in the outer scope, so that every function "sees" the same player.

```
var player;

function playSound(fileName) {
    if (player) {
        player.stop();
    }

    player = new Player(fileName);
    player.play();
}
```

This is called a closure.

Comment: Ah, wonderful.  I should have known to reassign player with every call.  Thanks for the spot-on answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your player should be static, only one instance should exist and play all sounds.

```
function Podcast() {};

Podcast.FILE_EXTENSION = 'mp3';
Podcast.download = function(podcast) {
    console.log('Downloading ' + podcast + ' ...');
};
```

Here we created a constructor function named Podcast with a static property called FILE_EXTENSION and a static method named download.

http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/19/basic-javascript-part-7-static-properties-and-methods/